# MemberPress remove course access after refund

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom plugin where customer purchase subscription from clickfunnel and pay through stripe after that I have created member and transaction via MemberPress API.

In case of refund MemberPress API does't work, now I have write the to refund from transaction table and member table but member still can access to all the purchased courses.

I have delete member data & transaction data from database, but it does not effect membership access.

https://docs.memberpress.com/article/219-where-is-data-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to revoke membership access from user account, you have to delete some entries from usermeta and postmeta togather.

Hope it will help.